# Linking an iOS application to a dropbox account hardcoded

Tags: ios, dropbox

I am trying to create an IOS application. Part of it will allow upload of data to a Dropbox account that is hardcoded. I don't know how to do this part of my app without having a webpage show up that asks for authorization. Are there other ways to authorize an account without asking the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Login Dropbox account on Core Api without Login Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834922/auto-login-dropbox-account-on-core-api-without-login-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. You're asking for a disaster.

- Violates the Dropbox Terms of Service.
- What happens when Dropbox suspends your account, your app breaks.
- An API key you hide in the app could be compromised and exploited.

Look into another service intended for what you actually want to accomplish, Amazon's S3 is likely a good choice.

Comment: thank you so much! dropbox was the first thing that popped to mind. what is your opinion on using parse?

Comment: Parse is dead. Depending on your use case, S3 is the most likely best option, could also use a Virtual Private Server with EC2, Digital Ocean, Linode, or any other similar company. You could possibly even use CloudKit. Would need to know more about your plans to know which is the best option.

Comment: Aside from +1 good answer, off topic: https://swiftforthereallyimpatient.com/ is giving me a certificate error (and doesn't seem to be pointing to the book).

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oops, sorry, don't use https for that site.