# Android Dropbox API v2 auto access using access token

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

In android API v1 I am able to pass access token through which I didn't need to login to Dropbox. In api v2 can you please let me know how to do that?

In API v2 auto access can be done without the following code -

```
Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this, Constants.APP_KEY);
```

Please provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK, you can still directly supply an access token without starting the authorization flow.

To do so, you can use a [`DbxClientV2` constructor](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxClientV2.html#DbxClientV2-com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig-java.lang.String-) that takes an OAuth 2 access token directly.

Note that it is still highly discouraged to distribute access tokens for a particular account in a client-side app, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834922/auto-login-dropbox-account-on-core-api-without-login-prompt).