# Is it possible to upload files from an without asking the user to sign in?

Tags: dropbox

I have a Dropbox account.
I would like to use it, so that an android app can upload photos to my Dropbox account, without the user of the app having to know my credentials to log in.

Is that possible ?

Is there a programmatic way, that I can get my app to do this, without the user of the app having to know my dropbox password ?

EDIT: I don't understand why this is down voted. If there are multiple posts asking how to do this, by different users, and it is with regard to finding a programmatic why to log in, then it is relevant and shouldn't be down voted.

Comment: You can technically do this as covered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975637/android-dropbox-api-v2-auto-access-using-access-token), but it's highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [thread](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/python-SDK-Create-file-requests/td-p/221676) on dropbox forums which says that they did not include the file requests feature in their apis so its not possible through apis.

Since the native api does not support this feature you can redirect your user from your app to dropbox app to create file requests.